# Understanding versions of .NET Core and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I can't understand difference between lot of `ASP.NET Core` framework names:
 - dnxcore50
 - dotnet5.4
 - netcoreapp

`dotnet5.4` is a new name for `dnxcore50`?

I create Class Library project and there is `dotent5.4` in `project.json`. Then I create empty ASP.NET project an dthere is `dnxcore50`.

I add dependency to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 1.0.0` to project and get error:

`The dependency Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore does not support for framework NETPlatform, Version=v5.4`

What is the correct framework version and Entity Framework version?

Comment: @DawoodAwan The whatnow?

Comment: If you get a new project with dotnet5.4 or dnxcore you clearly use heavy outdated versions of the tools. dnxcore and dotnet monikers are deprecated since rc2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can **avoid** so many issues if you use the `latest` tools and frameworks.

Here is the link : [**Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and .NET Core 1.0**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/06/27/visual-studio-2015-update-3-and-net-core-1-0-available-now/)

[image]

**What are the Target Framework Monikers (TFMs) ?**

> The Target Framework Monikers are IDs of the type framework+version
>   that you can target from your apps in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core.

**As examples, you can use:**

– “netcoreapp1.0” For .NET Core 1.0

– “net45”, “net451”, “net452”, “net46”, “net461” for .NET Framework versions

– “portable-net45+win8” for PCL profiles

– “dotnet5.6”, “dnxcore50” and others, for older .NET Core preview versions (Before .NET Core 1.0 RTM and .NET Core RC2 were released)

– “netstandard1.2”, “netstandard1.5”, etc. for .NET Standard Platform monikers.

**The table below** defines some examples of the latest frameworks (as of late June 2016) that you can use and how they are referred to and which version of the .NET Standard Library they implement :

[image]

**You can read about it here :** [**Running .NET Core apps on multiple frameworks and (TFMs)**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2016/06/28/running-net-core-apps-on-multiple-frameworks-and-what-the-target-framework-monikers-tfms-are-about/)

Answer (score 5):

Update your project.json as per current NuGet identifiers.

For version understanding, refer this-

[image]

For Entity Framework refer this - https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/efcore-vs-ef6/choosing.html

Reference: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#deprecated-monikers